# Returning 'Decimal' value returns Decimal('value') while printing it does not

Tags: python, decimal

When I return a Decimal value and print it:

```
return Decimal(number).quantize(Decimal(str(1 / 10 ** digits)), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

it prints the output within this `Decimal('')`

Example:

```
[Decimal('1.20') Decimal('1.22') Decimal('1.42') Decimal('1.75') Decimal('2.77')]
```

But when I print the value in the function itself it prints only the value.

Example:

```
1.20
1.20
1.22
1.42
1.75
2.77
```

Once I exit the function how can I get the numeric value without the it being inside `Decimal('')`

Thank you.

Comment: You must not be printing it the same way in both cases. The first result is printing the list in one step, the second result looks like you wrote a loop that printed each element separately.

Comment: Inside a list, it will use the `repr`esentation of Decimal, which is different. You could use `[str(x) for x in list_of_decimals]` instead.

Comment: @9769953 But then it will print them with quotes around them when you print the list.

Comment: Your first and second example aren't the same: the first is a single Decimal, the second a list of Decimals (or almost a list: there are commas missing, so I'm not 100% sure what it is). That makes a difference.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but one shouldn't print the list in the first place, and expect nicely formatted results. That's not what a list is for.

Comment: Show the code that you're using to print the value in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I return a Decimal value and print it:
>
> return Decimal(number).quantize(Decimal(dstr(1 / 10 ** digits)),
>   rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
>
> it prints the output within this Decimal('')

That is not true. You didn't print it. Your interpreter displayed something after returning the value. In fact, it chose to display the string returned by `<your_decimal_object>.__repr__()`

When you call `print`, you display the string returned by `<your_decimal_object>.__str__()`

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> def decimal_function(number, digits, ROUND_HALF_UP):
        return Decimal(number).quantize(Decimal(str(1 / 10 ** digits)), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

>>> a = decimal_function(1.0, 2, 'ROUND_HALF_UP')

>>> a

Decimal('1.00') 

>>> print(a)

1.00

>>> repr(a) # same as a.__repr__()

"Decimal('1.00')"

>>> str(a) # same as a.__str__()

'1.00'
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) to understand the different purposes of repr and str

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the values of `number` and `digits` are, but say:

```
from decimal import *
number = 10
digits = 2

x = Decimal(number).quantize(Decimal(str(1 / 10 ** digits)), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

print(x)
>>> Decimal('10.00')
type(x)
>>> <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
float(x)
>>> 10.0
```

Comment: `quantize()` returns a list, you can't convert that to a float.

Comment: This also negates the benefit of using the `Decimal` type, which avoids the inaccuracies of floating point.

Comment: I'm sure it does, but they asked "Once I exit the function how can I get the numeric value without the it being inside Decimal('')". I'm assuming using `Decimal()` within the function is where it's useful, but they want a number to be returned.

Comment: No, they just don't want `Decimal` to be printed.

Comment: `Decimal` values are numbers, they just use fixed-point arithmetic instead of floating point.